# how to blacklist people to prevent them add my bot?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make blacklist of users which can't add my bot to ther servers.
Here is my code
I'm on discord.js 12

```
const blacklist = ['159985870458322944'];

client.on('guildCreate', (guild) => {
    if(blacklist.includes(guild.owner)) return guild.leave();
});
```

Comment: `guild.owner` should be either [`guild.ownerID`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/Guild?scrollTo=ownerID) or  `guild.owner.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
guild.owner
```

to

```js
guild.ownerID
```

and your owner may have not an owner but can have administrator in server. So you can use;

```js
client.on("guildCreate", async guild => {
if(blacklist.includes(guild.ownerID)) return guild.leave();
if(blacklist.some(x => guild.members.cache.get(x) && guild.members.cache.get(x).permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR"))) return guild.leave();
})
```